# Mysql select results that have only a specific condition

Tags: mysql

here is my problem: I have a list of users that are associated with different international projects,
I want to get the users that are working exclusively for US projects, so let's say if someone has worked for a German project, I don't want him in the list.
It involves three tables: users, projects, company

Here is the first query to get users that are working for US projects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.forename, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM projects, company, users
WHERE projects.project_type = 'US'
AND company.project_id = projects.project_id
AND users.company_id = company.company_id
ORDER BY surname, forename
```

Now how can I exclude users that have also other countries' projects?

Comment: Can you post the table structure. A screenshot ?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses, I've tried only the NOT IN solution, and it works fine, just need to doublecheck, I will try also the other ones, they seem interesting. Thank you again

Comment: @HelterSkelter before trying make sure you will be prevented from future cause....just like i have commented on Narek answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT IN clause to exclude user that work on other project.

In where condition add below line

```
WHERE projects.user_id 
  NOT IN (select user_id from projects where projects.project_type != 'US')
```

Comment: The first condition (with `NOT IN`) would work, but with the second condition you do not exclude users, who have projects of other countries. You include any user, who has a US project, but it is not sufficient..

Answer (score 1):

You can join your tables and filter with the condition

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.forename, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM users
JOIN company USING (company_id)
JOIN projects USING (project_id)
WHERE projects.project_type = 'US'
ORDER BY surname, forename
```

this query creates rows with users and information about the company and the project and after filter these rows with the  condition `WHERE projects.project_type = 'US'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [HAVING](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx). If user worked only in US then COUNT need to be 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.forename, COUNT(projects.*) AS c, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM projects, company, users
WHERE projects.project_type = 'US'
AND company.project_id = projects.project_id
AND users.company_id = company.company_id
GROUP BY projects.project_type
HAVING c = 1
ORDER BY surname, forename
```

Maybe this code doesn't work, can't check but you can try in this direction.

Comment: Even with `GROUP BY projects.project_type` ?

Comment: @Narek i think you are counting total project user has...so may be sometime we have situation when one user work on two project which are also from `US`.

Comment: @DipeshParmar maybe, without working DB it little hard to check. But I'm sure there will be solution with HAVING, just need to play little with it.

Comment: @DipeshParmar is right and my first comment was also right. You could say `count (distinct projects.project_type)` instead and (maybe) it would work..

Comment: @agim yes your first comment is right but we still have `(maybe)` in mind so we can not lead OP to wrong way..

Comment: maybe was a joke, you have to use `distinct project_type`, otherwise you'll get a wrong result :-)

Answer (score 0):

A `not exists` would do the job

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.forename, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM projects, company, users
WHERE projects.project_type = 'US'
AND company.project_id = projects.project_id
AND users.company_id = company.company_id
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
      FROM projects notUS 
     WHERE notUS.project_type <> 'US' 
       AND notUS.user_id = users.user_id)
ORDER BY surname, forename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.forename, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM projects, company, users
WHERE users.company_id = company.company_id
AND company.project_id = projects.project_id
AND projects.user_id 
IN (select user_id from projects where projects.project_type = 'US')
ORDER BY surname, forename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think you need MINUS:

```
SELECT 
    users.forename, users.surname, users.email, users.company_id,  users.user_id
FROM 
    users
where 
    user_id not in(SELECT DISTINCT user_id from users where company_id in
    (
        Select company_id from company where project_id = (
            Select project_id from projects where project_type != 'US'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this too

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  users.forename,
  users.surname,
  users.email,
  users.company_id,
  users.user_id
FROM projects
  INNER JOIN company
    ON company.project_id = projects.project_id
  INNER JOIN users
    ON users.company_id = company.company_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT *
          FROM projects
          WHERE project_type <> 'US') AS project
    ON project.project_id = projects.project_id
WHERE project.project_id IN NULL
GROUP BY projects.project_id
ORDER BY surname, forename
```